# VBA ACCESS - Loop Excel workbooks

Tags: ms-access, vba

The following vba opens an excel workbook checks to see if its in read-only mode, if it is then waits till read/write is active then runs code. Simple

My Questions is that I have a lot of excel files e.g C:\TEST\TEST.xlsb, C:\TEST\TEST2.xlsb ,C:\TEST\TEST3.xlsb ,C:\TEST\TEST4.xlsb etc

How do I get the VBA to run code through each workbook name

Save me time copy/pasting code several times for each workbook name.

```
Function test()

Dim xl As Object

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xl.Workbooks.Open ("C:\TEST\Test.xlsb")

Do Until xl.ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = False

MsgBox ("Workbook in use, waiting till read/write is active")
Call Pause(5)
xl.Quit
xl.Workbooks.Open ("C:\TEST\Test.xlsb")
If xl.ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = False Then Exit Do
Loop


If xl.ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = False Then

MsgBox ("read/write active")

'Run code
xl.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2").Value = 2222
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
xl.Quit

End If

xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a loop to go through your files and call the function for every file. 
if the pattern of your filenames is something like this C:\TEST\TEST.xlsb, C:\TEST\TEST2.xlsb ,C:\TEST\TEST3.xlsb ,C:\TEST\TEST4.xlsb 
then you could for example implement another function to build the filename as a string and set it as a paramter of your function "test"

```
 Function goThroughFiles()
 Dim front as String
 Dim ending as String
 Dim i as Integer
 Dim strPath as String

 front = C:\TEST\TEST
 ending = .xlsb 
 i = 1

 // start with filename that has no number in it
 strPath = front & ending

 // check if file exists
 Do Until Len(Dir(strPath)) = 0 
    call test(strPath)
    i = i+1
    strPath = front & i & ending
 Loop
```

you need to change your original function, so it accepts a parameter:

```
  Function test(strPath as String)
```

and substitute every line that uses the path with your input variable

```
  xl.Workbooks.Open ("C:\TEST\Test.xlsb")
```

becomes

```
  xl.Workbooks.Open (strPath)
```

Comment: you need to find a pattern in the names that you can generate by code. or if the names change, then you could put all workbooks in a folder and loop through the files of the folder. if the names are changing and folders are different and there is nothing constant, then code won't help you and you need to do it manually

Comment: all the files in one folder , only thing that changes is the file names. Many thanks

Comment: then use this thread to rewrite the function "goThroughFiles" and you got it  :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba