# How to process Excel workbooks via Access VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, excel-2013

I have an Excel user form and some Excel VBA code that transforms some of the worksheet data into a format ready for import to an Access application.
The code works fine but I've decided that it would be much better for development and operations if the form and code were moved over to reside within the Access application, rather than the spreadsheet.

Where can I learn how to convert my Excel VBA code to work within Access or at least where is a reference on coding to process Excel within Access VBA?

Based solely on 
[VBA ACCESS - Loop Excel workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423907/vba-access-loop-excel-workbooks)
I have so far managed to start with this (Note: all of the following are just snippets.):

```
Private source_empl_col As Integer
Private xl_app As Object

Set xl_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl_app.Workbooks.Open (workbook_txt)
```

and I've managed to convert

```
Private source_sheet As Worksheet

Set source_sheet = Worksheets(source_cbo.Text)
source_sheet.Activate

Dim ws As Integer
For ws = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    source_cbo.AddItem Worksheets(ws).Name
```

from Excel VBA into Access VBA

```
xl_app.Sheets(source_cbo).Activate

Dim ws As Integer
For ws = 1 To xl_app.Worksheets.Count
    source_cbo.AddItem xl_app.Worksheets(ws).Name
```

without error. However, when it comes to converting

```
source_empl_col = Range(empl_col_txt & 1).Column
```

from Excel VBA into Access VBA

```
source_empl_col = xl_app.Sheets(source_cbo).Range(empl_col_txt.Text & 1).Column
```

or even just

```
source_empl_col = xl_app.Sheets(source_cbo).Range("B1").Column
```

I get

> Run-time error: '91'
>   Object variable ... not set.

There's just too much code that I need to translate so it works within Access without knowing what I'm doing.
Some guidance is needed!

Comment: Finally! Someone who sees spreadsheets are not databases and not user interfaces and not scalable in application and automation environments!

Comment: Not quite sure where you're coming from, @Parfait, but i'll take it as a compliment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Access VBA, to utilize the object model of external Office applications, namely here Excel (but also same rules apply for Outlook, PowerPoint, Word, etc.) requires explicitly declaring foreign objects.

What you need is an explicit declaration and setting of the [workbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx) object. You jumped from *app* directly to *sheet*, forgetting the middle man -*workbook*.

```
Dim xl_app As Object, xl_wkb As Object
Dim source_empl_col As Integer

Set xl_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xl_wkb = xl_app.Workbooks.Open (workbook_txt)

source_empl_col = xl_wkb.Sheets(source_cbo).Range(empl_col_txt.Text & 1).Column
```

Alternatively, you can even set the [worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) object:

```
Dim xl_app As Object, xlwkb As Object, xl_wks As Object
Dim source_empl_col As Integer

Set xl_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xl_wkb = xl_app.Workbooks.Open (workbook_txt)        
Set xl_wks = xl_wkb.Sheets(source_cbo)

source_empl_col = xl_wks.Range(empl_col_txt.Text & 1).Column
```